# Jquery and laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to use Jquery for my datapicker , but it doesnt work.

I added my class and an image about the error

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $("#from_date").datapicker();
        $("#to_date").datapicker();
    });
});
</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SyaJ.png)

Comment: Can you show us what the problem is?

Comment: Is the mention of laravel of any importance here?

Answer (score 0):

It's called dat**e**picker, therefore you should use

`$("#from_date").datepicker();`

instead of

`$("#from_date").datapicker();`

Comment: r/emboldenthee?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- You are looking for `datepicker` instead of `datapicker` (note the **`e`**)
- You've forgotten to actually *include* the relevant **[DatePicker](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)** JavaScript (this is separate to both Bootstrap and jQuery, and can be found at **[the JavaScript CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js)**)

Correcting both of these problems resolves the issue, as can be seen in the following:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.7.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
      $("#from_date").datepicker();
      $("#to_date").datepicker();
    });
  });
</script>

<input id="from_date">
<input id="to_date">
```

Hope this helps! :)